# Get the HTML content of a page after the JS loading

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get the results of a search in the Rust documentation. I made this code to do it :

```
let HTMLParser = require('node-html-parser');
let https = require('https');
const search = "foo";
let options = {
    host: "doc.rust-lang.org",
    path: "/std/index.html?search=" + search
};

let request = https.get(options, (res) => {
    if (res.statusCode != 200) return console.log(`An error occured : ${res.statusCode}. Retry later.`);
    res.setEncoding("utf8");

    let output = "";

    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
        output += chunk
    });

    res.on("end", () => {
        let root = HTMLParser.parse(output);
        console.log(root.querySelector(".search-results")); // print "null" because the search is not done when the request response come
    });

    request.end();
});
```

But when I run this code, I get the HTML content of the index.html page like if I requested this page without the `?search="foo"`. I found that the page change dynamically with some JS when we search for something, and then the base content is set to hidden and the search div become visible. So it seems that the JS didn't load when I get the request result, but I needs it to get the results of the search in the documentation. I don't know how I can do that.
Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: If you want to execute the page, you will have to literally do that. Right now, you don't: you get the page _source code_ and your code runs that through HTMLParser, which turns _that source code_ into a DOM you can query. If you want to actually execute the page, like in a real browser, then you _probably_ want to use a real browser in headless mode, or use something like puppeteer or selenium or phantomjs. That's a lot more work, but then "running a page like in a browser" simply _is_ a lot of work. No way around that.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the search results?

Comment: I'm trying to do a discord command for my bot that can search an element in the Rust documentation to give it easily to some members. What library should I use between puppeteer, selenium or phantomjs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rust doc page does not seem to hit a backend when a search is performed. I noticed this using the browser developer tools.

It looks like the page loads a [search-index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/search-index1.40.0.js) which contains the readily available docs. You can use this js to search for docs. The logic is written in the [main.js](https://doc.rust-lang.org/main1.40.0.js).

Let me know if you are looking for more info, as I have not found out how the link generation on each doc item is created.

**EDIT**

All the logic required to build the url is in [main.js](https://doc.rust-lang.org/main1.40.0.js). The method is as follows. If you take a close look at the aliases.js, main.js, storage.js and search-index.js files, you can reuse almost all of it to create the links and the required search outputs.

```js
function buildHrefAndPath(item) {
      var displayPath;
      var href;
      var type = itemTypes[item.ty];
      var name = item.name;
      if (type === 'mod') {
        displayPath = item.path + '::';
        href = rootPath + item.path.replace(/::/g, '/') + '/' + name + '/index.html'
      } else if (type === 'primitive' || type === 'keyword') {
        displayPath = '';
        href = rootPath + item.path.replace(/::/g, '/') + '/' + type + '.' + name + '.html'
      } else if (type === 'externcrate') {
        displayPath = '';
        href = rootPath + name + '/index.html'
      } else if (item.parent !== undefined) {
        var myparent = item.parent;
        var anchor = '#' + type + '.' + name;
        var parentType = itemTypes[myparent.ty];
        if (parentType === 'primitive') {
          displayPath = myparent.name + '::'
        } else {
          displayPath = item.path + '::' + myparent.name + '::'
        }
        href = rootPath + item.path.replace(/::/g, '/') + '/' + parentType + '.' + myparent.name + '.html' + anchor
      } else {
        displayPath = item.path + '::';
        href = rootPath + item.path.replace(/::/g, '/') + '/' + type + '.' + name + '.html'
      }
      return [displayPath,
      href]
    }
```

Comment: I have added more info on the link generation. You can use the main.js, storage.js and search-index.js as-is into your application and remove the styling related pieces.. It should work as is, since it is javascript.

Comment: I'm a little lost with all of this, what is the item argument taken by the function ? How should I use exactly these scripts to work with the code ?

Comment: I'm still confused on what to do with these scripts in the code

Comment: Err, you will have to debug that entire page multiple times on a browser like Mozilla. There is a starting point, where it looks for the search item, then does a levenshtein, then picks up all the matched objects, pass to this function, get the link, get the doc and etc..

Comment: If you have more questions, let's chat here - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102958/post-59617234

Comment: If you're still ok tomorrow, I'll stay in this room so we can continue to talk, because I'm still a bit lost even with your explanations of what to do